# How to combine multiple similar csv files in one file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have different CSV files in a folder.

Eg:

```
Master_data_0112207518.csv       3MB
Master_data_0112272018.csv       2MB
Master_data_0112232018.csv       7MB
Master_data_Loop_0110452018.csv  5MB
Master_data_Loop_0110222018.csv  7MB
Master_data_Loop_0110372018.csv  6MB
```

I have to write a python code to select same beginning name of files and create a merged file of this data group in one csv file.

output:

Total Number of different files : 2

```
['Master_data.csv', 'Master_data_Loop.csv']
```

After combination:

```
Master_data.csv       12MB
Master_data_Loop.csv  18MB
```

Comment: You have to post some of your code. ``SO is not a free-coding website``

Comment: What is your question?